# recursion number of possible paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

There is a terraced structure with N floors (here, for example 4 floors). Each floor has 4 cells.

[image]

Write the recursive function that describes the number of all the possible paths from the left bottom cell to the top right cell.
We can go up, down, right but not left and we can't visit in the same cell again.
Use only one variable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Interesting question... What are your thoughts about it? What have you try already? What issues are you facing?

Comment: i tried to find the base cases but in could'nt  find the function

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234433/generalizing-the-catalan-numbers?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to break it down. The terraced structures can be composed by combining two consecutive triangular shapes from this series:

```
n=2    n=3      n=4
                      1
           1        O 2
  1      O 2      O O 3
O 2    O O 3    O O O 4  ...
```

so now the question becomes:

> How many paths (using NSE-directions, ie. north south east) can be formed in $T_n$, the triangular shape with $n$ layers ending at one of the numbered positions? Let $P_n(k)$ denote the number of paths in $T_n$ starting from the bottom left corner ending in the numbered position $k$ on the right side of the triangle.

### Analysis of triangular shapes

For $n=2$ we have $P_2(1)=P_2(2)=1$, because we have one path leading to each numbered position:

```
   1*      1
 ──┘     ──2*
```

For $n=3$ this becomes $P_3(k)=2$, since you can make a path to either one of the end positions in $T_2$ and then move into the last column in $T_3$ and reach the desired end position:

```
     1*      1       1             1*      1       1
   ┌─┘     ┌─2*    ┌─┐           O │     O 2*    O 2
 ──┘ 3   ──┘ 3   ──┘ 3*   and  ────┘   ────┘   ────3*
```

This principle generalizes, and it follows that $P_n(k)$ is equal for all $k$. Let us hence denote this number simply by $P_n$. Then we have the recursive formula (and obvious solution to it):
$$
P_n=(n-1)P_{n-1}=(n-1)!
$$

### Analysis of terraced structure

Given the terrace of size $n$, $S_n$, this can be combined from two triangles:
$$
S_n\sim T_n + T_{n-1}
$$
so for instance $S_3$ can be seen as follows

```
    3─2 2
  3 3─2
3 3 3
```

where the top right corner is $T_2$ placed upside down. Any solution to the original problem will be a connection of paths in the two triangular shapes through one of the connections marked with a line in the figure above. Hence we have:

> A solution to the $S_n$ terrace problem, can be constructed by combining a path to one of the top $n-1$ positions in $T_n$ to any end position in $T_{n-1}$. Let $K_n$ denote the number of such paths.

This leads to the recursive formula:
$$
K_n=(n-1)P_n\cdot P_{n-1}=(n-1)!^2
$$

---

For instance we get $K_2=1!^2=1$ and $K_3=2!^2=4$ and $K_4=3!^2=36$ which you can easily make a sanity check for.

---

It just occurred to me that one could simply place two $T_n$ triangles with a one column overlap in the middle. This leads directly to:
$$
K_n=(P_n)^2=(n-1)!^2
$$

Comment: Excellent solution! I was wondering if my solution was in the right direction. This is great, just to clarify that NSE-directions means north, sourth, East direction! I got really confused with that haha

Comment: @user614287: Thank you. Yes, I thought for a moment whether to write NSE in a different manner. Perhaps I should edit to make that clear.

Comment: Why gluing two triangles in the middle produces $K_n = (n-1)!^2$?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a total of $9$ moves to get to the right upper cell in the grid starting from the lower left cell. At any given moment during your moves, The number of right moves made so far is always larger than or equals to the number of up moves made so far. Also, at any given time, the difference between number of right moves and the number of up moves seen so far should not be greater than $3$.

We can translate those condition into restriction on formulas, so we first give definition of some variables.

We let $r$ denote the number of possible right moves that you can still make so far, let $l$ be the number of possible left moves you can still make so far and let $t$ be the number of moves you can still make. Then $r+l=3$(because each time you make a right move, the number of right moves you can still make decreases by $1$ and the number of up moves that you can make increases by $1$) and $t=9$ initially.

let $H(r,l,t)$ be the number of ways to finish all your moves where you can still make $r$ right moves, $l$ left moves and $t$ more moves. Then $H(r,l,t)=1+H(r-1,l+1,t-1)+H(r+1,l-1,t-1)$ The base cases is: $H(r,l,t)=0$ if $(t=0) \vee (r<0) \vee (l<0)$ and you want to solve $H(3,0,9)$.

Hope this is a good recursion.

Comment: I need to slove it for N floors ( 4 was just example), and i i need to use with only one variable

Comment: Ok! so the total number of steps that you have to take if you have 1 floor is $3$, if you add one more floor, then you have yo move up once and move right once, so in total, you will have $3+2$ moves. So each times you add a floor, the total number of moves that you should make increases by 2. So in general, if you have $N$ floors, you have to make $2(N-1)+3$ moves. So if you have to solve the problem for $N$ floor, you would compute $H(3,0,2(N-1)+3)$. Lemme think about how we can do it with only one variable.

Comment: If we let $rr$ be the number right step made so far and $ll$ be the number of left steps made so far, then $H(r,l,t)=H(rr-ll,3-(rr-ll),2(N-1)+3-(rr+ll))$ and this gives two variable?

Comment: wait i can't use left moves, only up,down and right

Comment: Oh I guess we have a solution from below now lol